# Connection Refused on phpMyAdmin

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am facing a database connection problem. I am not sure what happens, but hope for experts' answers. :)

Here is my situation. I am developing an ASP .NET MVC web application using VS Community for MAC version 7.4.3 (build 10), and MAMP version 4.4.1.

I have do the following code and setup the database in phpMyAdmin provided by MAMP. Here are the details for the settings.

**connection string in web.config:**

```
> <connectionStrings>
>     <add name="SchoolSystem" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=SchoolSystem;User
> ID=root;Password=root" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />  
> </connectionStrings>
```

**Source code:**

```
public ActionResult Add()
        {
            string mainConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchoolSystem"].ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection mysql = new MySqlConnection(mainConn);
            string query = "SELECT * from UserRole;";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query);
            command.Connection = mysql;
            mysql.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dr["UserRoleID"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(dr["UserRoleName"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(dr["IsAll"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(dr["IsAddStudent"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(dr["IsDeleteStudent"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(dr["IsAddTeacher"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(dr["IsDeleteTeacher"].ToString());
            }
            mysql.Close();
            return View();
        }
```

**phpMyAdmin configuration:**

PHP

```
phpinfo shows the current configuration of PHP.

MySQL

MySQL can be administered with phpMyAdmin.

To connect to the MySQL server from your own scripts use the following connection parameters:

Host    localhost
Port    3306
User    root
Password    root
Socket  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
phpMyAdmin URL:

http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin/sql.php?db=SchoolSystem&table=UserRole&token=1cd40620cbc2325e1f15a1c443f327af&pos=0
```

**Error message:**

```
<div id="header"> <div id="header-text">Application Exception</div> </div> <div id="main">
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Connection refused

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.

<div>Exception stack trace:</div> <div class="details"></div> <div id="footer"> <div>Version Information: 5.8.1.0 (2017-10/6bf3922f3fd Thu Mar 8 17:00:31 EST 2018); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.42000</div> </div> </div>
```

Appreciate any help provided.

Comment: An error 500 might have a more descriptive error logged in the webserver error log. See if you can find some hints there.

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to find any potential errors that cause the connection refusal. I looked through mysql_error_log.err and apache_error.log, but no error found except this "[Fri Apr 27 21:49:36 2018] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" seem unrelated error. Do you have other recommendations on debugging?

Comment: I thought Visual Studio came with its own IIS instance for development; what is the full URL your browser is loading (including any port number such as `http://localhost:5000/`)?

Comment: I am using the VS community Mac version. As I was told by others in other forum that I need to set up Apache and mysql server. So I go for MAMP. I tried with the PHP script before, it can access the db, but when I try to create asp .net web apps, it gives this error. I am new to web development using asp .net, I could be wrong. I need some guidance.

The loading URL is http://127.0.0.1:8080